# Knowing the assigned name of a cell instead of the "A1" name

Tags: vba, excel

**Context:**
I have several lists in my sheet (1 column wide, 1-10 rows long). When I right click a cell in these lists, I can do several options, that all work well. I have given a name to the cell at the top of each of these lists (ex. Cell A1 has been given the name cell_1, B10 is names cell_2, etc).

I would like to know if the cell I am right clicking on is the one at the top of the list; is it named "cell_(number)"? If it is not, it checks the cell on top of that one. Does it have a name that starts with "cell_"? If not, check the one on top, etc. Until I can figure out the user clicked on an element of WHICH list.

**TL;DR The actual question**
I can use ActiveCell.Address, which gives me something like "A1" whether or not I have assigned a name to that cell. ActiveCell.Name gives "Sheet1!A1", so it's not much better. Any idea how to get it to return the name I have assigned instead?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Name.Name` will work if the cell has a name, otherwise it will raise an error, which you'll have to trap.

Comment: Very nice one, Tim Williams.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim! That was... counter intuitive, to say the least!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UDF to test the application names, it's less efficient but contains error handling within the function itself:

```
Sub SO()
'// Example how to call function
Debug.Print GetCellName(Range("A1"))

End Sub


Function GetCellName(myCell As Excel.Range) As Variant
Dim nameCheck As Variant

For Each nameCheck In Application.Names
    If Replace(Replace(Replace(nameCheck, "=", ""), "'", ""), "!", "") = _
        CStr(myCell.Parent.Name & myCell.Address) Then

        GetCellName = CStr(nameCheck.Name)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

GetCellName = CVErr(Excel.xlErrName)

End Function
```

Note you can also use this function in a worksheet cell like so:

**=GetCellName(A1)**

Comment: It is true that activecell.name.name returns a 1004 error when the active cell has not been given one. This will prevent such an error? What will be returned if the cell has not been given a name? Thanks, by the way.

Comment: On a spreadsheet, it will return a `#NAME?` error. In VBA it will return the text `Error 2029` but shouldn't halt code execution. Without knowing what context you are using it in I can't give a definitive answer. My advice would be to just test it and see what happens

Comment: Hmmm. It seems I get an error 13 (type incompatibility) when I select a cell that has no assigned name. The error occurs because the function ends without returning a value. I worked around this by replacing the last line with getCellName = "nothing". In my code, if the returned name is "nothing" I look in the cell above. if the name is "cell_" I have hit my target. Thanks for the help buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work.  This function returns the names assigned to a cell (or bigger range for that matter).  If there's more than one name, it returns it as an array for array formula...or the user can supply an index to return only the desired name position

```
Public Function CellIsInRangeNames(sheetname As String, checkRange As Range, Optional itemNumber As Variant) As Variant
   Dim oNM As Name
   Dim oSht As Worksheet
   Dim isect As Range
   Dim namesCollection() As Variant
   Set oSht = Worksheets(sheetname)

   Dim i As Integer
   i = -1
   For Each oNM In oSht.Names
       Set isect = Application.Intersect(Range(oNM.Name), checkRange)
       If Not isect Is Nothing Then
           i = i + 1
           ReDim Preserve namesCollection(0 To i)
           namesCollection(i) = CStr(oNM.Name)
       End If
   Next oNM

   If i = -1 Then
       'didn't find any
       CellIsInRangeNames = xlErrName
   ElseIf Not IsMissing(itemNumber) Then
       'user wanted this instance only
       If (itemNumber - 1 > UBound(namesCollection)) Or (itemNumber - 1 < LBound(namesCollection)) Then
           CellIsInRangeNames = xlErrValue
       Else
           CellIsInRangeNames = namesCollection(itemNumber - 1)
       End If
   Else  'here's the list as an array
       CellIsInRangeNames = namesCollection
   End If   

End Function
```